# Smart card logon in Windows in domain FreeIPA

Tags: windows, certificate, smartcard, freeipa

I create domain with FreeIPA.
I connected Windows 10 to it. Login to Windows by login-password is successful.
I create a profile in the FreeIPA settings to create certificates for Smart Card Login in Windows.

```
auth.instance_id=raCertAuth
classId=caEnrollImpl
desc=Enroll user certificates with smartcardlogon.
enable=true
enableBy=ipara
input.i1.class_id=certReqInputImpl
input.i2.class_id=submitterInfoInputImpl
input.list=i1,i2
name=IPA-RA Agent-Authenticated Server Certificate Enrollment
output.list=o1
output.o1.class_id=certOutputImpl
policyset.list=serverCertSet
policyset.serverCertSet.1.constraint.class_id=subjectNameConstraintImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.1.constraint.name=Subject Name Constraint
policyset.serverCertSet.1.constraint.params.accept=true
policyset.serverCertSet.1.constraint.params.pattern=(UID|CN)=.*
policyset.serverCertSet.1.default.class_id=subjectNameDefaultImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.1.default.name=Subject Name Default
policyset.serverCertSet.1.default.params.name=CN=$request.req_subject_name.cn$, O=FREEIPA.RED, DC=FREEIPA, DC=RED, E=$request.req_subject_name.cn$@FREEIPA.RED
policyset.serverCertSet.10.constraint.class_id=noConstraintImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.10.constraint.name=No Constraint
policyset.serverCertSet.10.default.class_id=subjectKeyIdentifierExtDefaultImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.10.default.name=Subject Key Identifier Extension Default
policyset.serverCertSet.10.default.params.critical=false
policyset.serverCertSet.11.constraint.class_id=noConstraintImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.11.constraint.name=No Constraint
policyset.serverCertSet.11.default.class_id=userExtensionDefaultImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.11.default.name=User Supplied Extension Default
policyset.serverCertSet.11.default.params.userExtOID=2.5.29.17
policyset.serverCertSet.12.constraint.class_id=noConstraintImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.12.constraint.name=No Constraint
policyset.serverCertSet.12.default.class_id=userExtensionDefaultImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.12.default.name=IECUserRoles Extension Default
policyset.serverCertSet.12.default.params.userExtOID=1.2.840.10070.8.1
policyset.serverCertSet.2.constraint.class_id=validityConstraintImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.2.constraint.name=Validity Constraint
policyset.serverCertSet.2.constraint.params.notAfterCheck=false
policyset.serverCertSet.2.constraint.params.notBeforeCheck=false
policyset.serverCertSet.2.constraint.params.range=740
policyset.serverCertSet.2.default.class_id=validityDefaultImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.2.default.name=Validity Default
policyset.serverCertSet.2.default.params.range=731
policyset.serverCertSet.2.default.params.startTime=0
policyset.serverCertSet.3.constraint.class_id=keyConstraintImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.3.constraint.name=Key Constraint
policyset.serverCertSet.3.constraint.params.keyParameters=1024,2048,3072,4096
policyset.serverCertSet.3.constraint.params.keyType=RSA
policyset.serverCertSet.3.default.class_id=userKeyDefaultImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.3.default.name=Key Default
policyset.serverCertSet.4.constraint.class_id=noConstraintImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.4.constraint.name=No Constraint
policyset.serverCertSet.4.default.class_id=authorityKeyIdentifierExtDefaultImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.4.default.name=Authority Key Identifier Default
policyset.serverCertSet.5.constraint.class_id=noConstraintImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.5.constraint.name=No Constraint
policyset.serverCertSet.5.default.class_id=authInfoAccessExtDefaultImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.5.default.name=AIA Extension Default
policyset.serverCertSet.5.default.params.authInfoAccessADEnable_0=true
policyset.serverCertSet.5.default.params.authInfoAccessADLocationType_0=URIName
policyset.serverCertSet.5.default.params.authInfoAccessADLocation_0=http://ipa-ca.freeipa.red/ca/ocsp
policyset.serverCertSet.5.default.params.authInfoAccessADMethod_0=1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1
policyset.serverCertSet.5.default.params.authInfoAccessCritical=false
policyset.serverCertSet.5.default.params.authInfoAccessNumADs=1
policyset.serverCertSet.6.constraint.class_id=keyUsageExtConstraintImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.6.constraint.name=Key Usage Extension Constraint
policyset.serverCertSet.6.constraint.params.keyUsageCritical=true
policyset.serverCertSet.6.constraint.params.keyUsageCrlSign=false
policyset.serverCertSet.6.constraint.params.keyUsageDataEncipherment=true
policyset.serverCertSet.6.constraint.params.keyUsageDecipherOnly=false
policyset.serverCertSet.6.constraint.params.keyUsageDigitalSignature=true
policyset.serverCertSet.6.constraint.params.keyUsageEncipherOnly=false
policyset.serverCertSet.6.constraint.params.keyUsageKeyAgreement=false
policyset.serverCertSet.6.constraint.params.keyUsageKeyCertSign=false
policyset.serverCertSet.6.constraint.params.keyUsageKeyEncipherment=true
policyset.serverCertSet.6.constraint.params.keyUsageNonRepudiation=true
policyset.serverCertSet.6.default.class_id=keyUsageExtDefaultImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.6.default.name=Key Usage Default
policyset.serverCertSet.6.default.params.keyUsageCritical=true
policyset.serverCertSet.6.default.params.keyUsageCrlSign=false
policyset.serverCertSet.6.default.params.keyUsageDataEncipherment=true
policyset.serverCertSet.6.default.params.keyUsageDecipherOnly=false
policyset.serverCertSet.6.default.params.keyUsageDigitalSignature=true
policyset.serverCertSet.6.default.params.keyUsageEncipherOnly=false
policyset.serverCertSet.6.default.params.keyUsageKeyAgreement=false
policyset.serverCertSet.6.default.params.keyUsageKeyCertSign=false
policyset.serverCertSet.6.default.params.keyUsageKeyEncipherment=true
policyset.serverCertSet.6.default.params.keyUsageNonRepudiation=true
policyset.serverCertSet.7.constraint.class_id=noConstraintImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.7.constraint.name=No Constraint
policyset.serverCertSet.7.default.class_id=extendedKeyUsageExtDefaultImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.7.default.name=Extended Key Usage Extension Default
policyset.serverCertSet.7.default.params.exKeyUsageCritical=true
policyset.serverCertSet.7.default.params.exKeyUsageOIDs=1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1,1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2,1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.2,1.3.6.1.5.2.3.5
policyset.serverCertSet.8.constraint.class_id=signingAlgConstraintImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.8.constraint.name=No Constraint
policyset.serverCertSet.8.constraint.params.signingAlgsAllowed=SHA1withRSA,SHA256withRSA,SHA512withRSA,MD5withRSA,MD2withRSA,SHA1withDSA,SHA1withEC,SHA256withEC,SHA384withEC,SHA512withEC
policyset.serverCertSet.8.default.class_id=signingAlgDefaultImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.8.default.name=Signing Alg
policyset.serverCertSet.8.default.params.signingAlg=-
policyset.serverCertSet.9.constraint.class_id=noConstraintImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.9.constraint.name=No Constraint
policyset.serverCertSet.9.default.class_id=crlDistributionPointsExtDefaultImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.9.default.name=CRL Distribution Points Extension Default
policyset.serverCertSet.9.default.params.crlDistPointsCritical=false
policyset.serverCertSet.9.default.params.crlDistPointsEnable_0=true
policyset.serverCertSet.9.default.params.crlDistPointsIssuerName_0=CN=Certificate Authority,o=ipaca
policyset.serverCertSet.9.default.params.crlDistPointsIssuerType_0=DirectoryName
policyset.serverCertSet.9.default.params.crlDistPointsNum=1
policyset.serverCertSet.9.default.params.crlDistPointsPointName_0=http://ipa-ca.freeipa.red/ipa/crl/MasterCRL.bin
policyset.serverCertSet.9.default.params.crlDistPointsPointType_0=URIName
policyset.serverCertSet.9.default.params.crlDistPointsReasons_0=
policyset.serverCertSet.13.constraint.class_id=noConstraintImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.13.constraint.name=No Constraint
policyset.serverCertSet.13.default.class_id=subjectAltNameExtDefaultImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.13.default.name=Subject Alt Name Constraint
policyset.serverCertSet.13.default.params.subjAltNameExtCritical=false
policyset.serverCertSet.13.default.params.subjAltExtType_0=RFC822Name
policyset.serverCertSet.13.default.params.subjAltExtPattern_0=$request.req_subject_name.cn$@FREEIPA.RED
policyset.serverCertSet.13.default.params.subjAltExtGNEnable_0=true
policyset.serverCertSet.13.default.params.subjAltExtType_1=OtherName
policyset.serverCertSet.13.default.params.subjAltExtPattern_1=(UTF8String)1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3,$request.req_subject_name.cn$@FREEIPA.RED
policyset.serverCertSet.13.default.params.subjAltExtGNEnable_1=true
set.serverCertSet.13.default.params.subjAltExtType_2=OtherName
policyset.serverCertSet.13.default.params.subjAltExtPattern_2=(UTF8String)1.3.6.1.5.2.2,$request.req_subject_name.cn$@FREEIPA.RED
policyset.serverCertSet.13.default.params.subjAltExtGNEnable_2=true
policyset.serverCertSet.13.default.params.subjAltNameNumGNs=3
policyset.serverCertSet.14.constraint.class_id=noConstraintImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.14.constraint.name=No Constraint
policyset.serverCertSet.14.default.class_id=commonNameToSANDefaultImpl
policyset.serverCertSet.14.default.name=Copy Common Name to Subject Alternative Name
policyset.serverCertSet.list=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14
profileId=SmartCardLogon
visible=false
```

Created a key and a certificate request via openssl:

```
#openssl genrsa -out test.pem 2048
#openssl req -new -out test.req -key test.pem
```

Issued a certificate to the user via FreeIPA.

I collected the key and certificate into a pfx container and imported this container to a smart card.

Winlogon return error:

> The remote procedure call failed

In System Event log Windows:

> The security package Kerberos generated an exception. The exception information is the data.

Tell me, maybe someone has faced a similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just to make clear: what you are trying to achieve is not supported by FreeIPA. You cannot join Windows systems to FreeIPA because FreeIPA itself is not an Active Directory. While simple things might appear working (password-based logon, for example), the rest is not and will not be working. FreeIPA is not designed to be an Active Directory domain controller. You can use Samba AD for that purpose.